# Getting release and expire dates directly from DB - Please confirm the query is right or not

Tags: database, api, umbraco

My website is a bit huge and looping through all the nodes using Umbraco APIs to get release and expire dates is timing out.. so I wrote the following query to find the expire and release dates of nodes..

```
SELECT D.nodeId, D.releaseDate, D.expireDate
FROM dbo.cmsDocument D  
WHERE D.newest = 1 AND  
(
    D.releaseDate IS NOT NULL  
    OR
    D.expireDate IS NOT NULL 
)
```

can any one please confirm whether its right or wrong... If its wrong, what is the proper way to get these values..

Thanks
Anz

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Umbraco, but I *do* know that not all dbms will use an index in evaluating expressions like `your_column_name IS NOT NULL`.

If your target dbms doesn't treat `IS NOT NULL` as a sargable expression, then it won't use an index. Instead, it will  do a full table scan, which can take a long time on a big table. And if it takes a long time, I suppose a timeout is still possible.

It's also possible that there isn't an index on releaseDate or expireDate. On a big table, that will slow you down a lot, too.

If you want to know which documents expired before today, maybe so you can delete them, I'd (perhaps naively) expect this standard SQL statement to work. (But I'd also expect some Umbraco housekeeping module to make this unnecessary.)

```
select nodeId
from cmsDocument
where expiredate < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info.. yes I can use something like expiredate < CURRENT_DATE ..